# title font size in ggplot2 does not change

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I know this is a very basic question, but I have trouble changing font size of axis labels in ggplot2. I used the code like below:

```
a <- ggplot(data1,  aes(x=data2, y=data3)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept=c(1, -1)) + 
labs(x = data2, y = data3) + 
theme_bw() + 
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10))
```

I tried to change the axis label size but they do not change.... Does anybody have suggestion?

Comment: axis labels, in the sense of the title of the axis, are controlled by `axis.title`, not `axis.text` (which controls the individual value labels along the axis).

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out here how to alter labels in ggplot: 
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-title-main-axis-and-legend-titles

In the example below we use `axis.title` to change the size, colour and face of the text.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars,  aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=10, colour = "red", face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same problem, and realised that if you have specified e.g. theme_classic() or theme_bw, then the theme() argument has to come AFTER it!

So

```
g +
theme_classic() +
theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 12))
```

will work, but

```
g +
theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 12)) +
theme_classic()
```

will not!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35529553)